# Radiobutton controls not sent to viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a view where users will choose a value with radiobuttons. My problem is that once the user clicks submit, the values in the View model (in my controller) are null. My view model is as follows:

```
public class PreconditionsViewModel
{
    public List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> Provinces { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/mm/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime SeedingDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/mm/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime HarvestDate { get; set; }

    public int DryMatterPercentage { get; set; }

    public int PostalCode { get; set; }

}
```

The Action method:
(for simplicity, I have left the method only returning an index. But I should be able to see what the model holds)

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(PreconditionsViewModel model)
    {            
        return View("Index");
    }
```

The View:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Precondition", FormMethod.Post, new { @class="userPreconditionForm" }))
{
    foreach (var province in Model.Provinces)
    {
        @Html.Label(province.Value, new { @class = "provinces" })
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => province.Key, province.Value)    
    }

    <br/><br />

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PostalCode, Resource.PostalCode)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PostalCode)
    <br/><br />

    @Html.Label(Resource.DesiredSeedingDate)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SeedingDate, new { @class="dateField", @readonly="true" } )
    <br/><br />

    @Html.Label(Resource.LatestHarvestDate)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HarvestDate, new { @class = "dateField", @readonly = "true" })
    <br/><br />

    @Html.Label(Resource.DesiredDryMatterPercentage)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DryMatterPercentage)

    <br/><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="@Resource.Continue" />
}

<br/>
```

As you probably can see, my erros are in the code:

```
foreach (var province in Model.Provinces)
{
    @Html.Label(province.Value, new { @class = "provinces" })
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => province.Key, province.Value)    
}
```

What I am trying to do here, is to create a label and radiobutton for each KeyValuePair in my ViewModel. But I am doing it wrong, since they are not recieved in the controller. What am I doing wrong?

(I am new with asp.net mvc, so critics and improvements are welcome)

---

Added edited code after @LeftyX's reply

```
foreach (var province in Model.Provinces)
{
    @Html.Label("Provinces_" + province.Key, province.Value, new { @class = "provinces" })
    @Html.RadioButton("Province", province.Key, new { id = "Provinces_" + province.Key })    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a property `Province` to your viewmodel `PreconditionsViewModel`:

```
public int Province { get; set; }
```

and in your view change the code for the radio buttons creation:

```
foreach (var province in Model.Provinces)
{
    @Html.Label("Provinces_" + province.Key, province.Value, new { @class = "provinces" })
    @Html.RadioButton("Province", province.Key, new { id="Provinces_" + province.Key})
}
```

Each radio control will be rendered this way:

```
<input id="Provinces_1" name="Province" type="radio" value="1">
<input id="Provinces_2" name="Province" type="radio" value="2">
```

As you can see each one of the inputs has a different `id` but the same `name`.

When you POST your form, the added property `Province` will be bound to the selected field.

You can try the solution in the zip file [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=669ADF1AF64DF389!249&authkey=!AHhD7gh023wYDyc&ithint=file%2Czip).

Comment: Where are you using the new property that you introduced in the ViewModel?
Thanks

Comment: I added my edit in my code above. I am still getting null values when the view is submitted. Have I missed something?
I also added the property int Province

Comment: @user3563643: the new property reads the value of the chosen province. I've updated my answer with some code (check the zip in the link).